# Não consigo executar códigos PHP no VS Code

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, terminal

Venho tentado executar códigos PHP no terminal do VS Code. Sempre que tento faze-lo aparece essa mensagem:

```
*c:~\Users\Thiago\Downloads\Training.php
\SP.php : O termo 'c:~\Users\Thiago\Dow 
nloads\Training.php\SP.php'* não é       
reconhecido como nome de cmdlet,        
função, arquivo de script ou programa   
operável. Verifique a grafia do nome    
ou, se um caminho tiver sido incluído,  
veja se o caminho está correto e tente  
novamente. não é       
reconhecido como nome de cmdlet,        
função, arquivo de script ou programa   
operável. Verifique a grafia do nome    
ou, se um caminho tiver sido incluído,  
veja se o caminho está correto e tente  
novamente.
```

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Como vc está tentando executar o código? Vc quer mesmo executar um script ou "criar um site"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A linguagem de programação PHP foi feita para trabalhar no servidor, para executar os scripts do PHP você terá que abrir um servidor, para abrir basta usar o XAMPP e iniciar o apache na tela inicial do XAMPP, para que possam ser executado os scripts em PHP precisará salvar os arquivos na pasta `C:/xampp/htdocs`. Também existe outra forma de abrir um servidor, a partir da versão 7 do PHP vem embutido servidor web, para executar bastar ir no diretório que foi salvo os arquivos em PHP e executar esse comando `php -S localhost:8080`, para executar os scripts irá precisar abrir o browser e acessar o `localhost`.